# Which test to use to examine if Likert responses tend to have the given value for each level of the independent variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ordinal-data, likert

I have one nominal variable, `City`, with 7 possible options, and one ordinal variable, which is actually a Likert scale about whether or not the citizens want to migrate.

The summary table looks similar to this:

```
         ||  I want to live in another city.
   City  || Strongly agree | Agree | Don't know | Disagree | Strongly disagree 
   City1 || 56             | 14    |    6       |  7       | 9
   ...      ...              ...        ...        ...       ...
   City7 || 45             | 20    |    14      |  9       | 5
```

(The values in the cells correspond to the number of citizens that selected the answer written in its column header.)

Since those cities are all close to one another and located in a poor area, the scientific hypothesis is that its residents do not like the cities they are living in and want to move out.

However, it is not clear to me which statistical test should I conduct in order to test the hypothesis. I first gave a thought to Chi squared, but the response variable is not nominal and I was taught that it is used to assess association of two nominal variables, so I disregarded it. :)

Could I somehow examine the hypothesis:

```
(Response = Strongly agree) or (Response = Agree) for each city.
```

I would need something like non-parametric one-sample t test for every city, but I'm not sure which test to use, since all the ones I know don't apply to this scenario, or at least it is what I learned.

What should I do?